# gtkmm display file contents

Tags: c++, file, gtk, gtkmm

I am quite new to gtkmm please be soft, I need to read a file contents and display it.
I have referred to this tut https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-buildapp-opening-files.html.en, but not sure how to tailor these example to my scenario, I am reading Gtk::TextView, GtkWidget. Can someone point to any simple examples to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this, it's in PHP but understandable https://www.kksou.com/php-gtk2/sample-codes/read-a-text-file-into-GtkTextView.php